# libgdx apply force in direction rectangle is facing

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I'm just starting out with box2d an I'm trying  to make a rocket(rectangle for now) fly, it just stands vertically when the game starts and I want to apply force from the bottom part of the rectangle, because that's where the engine would be, and also in the direction the rectangle is facing.
I tried doing this

```
    body.applyLinearImpulse(getUserData().getBoosterLinearImpulse(), new Vector2(body.getWorldCenter().x, body.getWorldCenter().y - Constants.ROCKET_HEIGHT), true);
```

This is a method that gets executed when the bottom right of the screen is pressed. It only works when the rectangle is standing still.
I obviously don't really know what I'm doing.
I also have another question: what's the difference between applyLineairForce and applyForce, and how do I best learn to work with box2d as I don't find it easy (which is not a problem)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right you want to know the difference between a applyLinearImpulse and a applyForce. An impulse is a one-off application of force which would generally be used for jumps in a game whereas a force would be something applied every frame say to increase the speed of a car.

In order for you to apply force to your rocket, you could use something like this:

```
       // gets x force based on angle
        float x = (float)Math.sin(body.getAngle() - Math.PI); // minus PI as objects start off facing right
        // gets y force based on angle
        float y = (float)Math.cos(body.getAngle());

        //apply force to center (applies force to middle so no rotation )
        //body.applyForceToCenter( new Vector2(
        //      body.getMass()* (x * 12),
        //      body.getMass()*(y*12)), true);

        //NOTE: bodies must be set to .fixedRotation = false in order to rotate;

        //apply force to a point on body (will create rotational force ) 
        body.applyForce( new Vector2(
                body.getMass()* (x * 12),//x force to apply
                body.getMass()* (y * 12)), //y force to apply
                // apply force to body at 0.5f(halfway for 1f wide object) x and -5 y
                body.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f,-5)),true);
```

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try to do that. Another question: how did you learn all this? Working with box2d? Because I'm having trouble understanding the libgdx/box2d documentation.

Comment: I personally learned through trial and error and a lot of reading the iforce2d [link](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/introduction) guides. Games from scratch has a nice tutorial [link](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/08/27/LibGDX-Tutorial-13-Physics-with-Box2D-Part-1-A-Basic-Physics-Simulations.aspx)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot I'll start doing that too. In you answer to the main question: could you explain the last line of code? Are you applying force on multiple parts of the body? How would you apply force to just the bottom so that the rockets goes up when standing vertical, so that it moves in the direction it's 'pointing'?

Comment: In the applyForce method the first 2 values are how much force for x and y should be applied. The Vector2 is the place the force should be applied. I have also updated my answer to use the body Location instead of the world location.

Comment: So this means that if you use getWorldPoint on a body, and in the vector you put half of the width of the body and in y 0, does that mean the force will always come from 0y and in the middle of the body?

Comment: (0,0) would be in the center of the object. In your case, to apply it from the bottom in the middle like a rocket you would use (0,-0.5) if it was 1f in height.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last thing: if the rocket turns horizontal, how do I still let the force be applied to the bottom part which is then faced left/right? (sorry for all the questions)

Comment: The "body.getWorldPoint(new Vector2(0.5f,-5)),true);" is relative to the body it's applying it to so will always apply it to the same part of the body no matter what angle it is facing.